# Implementations and Collections

Tags: java, generics, collections, interface

**Why does this not work...**

```
public ArrayList<Edge> getEdges() {

return A;

//A is an Arraylist of type 'Action'. Action implements Edge.

}
```

the interface Edge includes: public ArrayList getEdges();

**even though this does.**

```
public Edge getEdges() {

return B;

//B is an 'Action'. Action implements Edge.

}
```

the interface Edge includes: public Edge getEdges();

Thank You,
Chet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because while `Edge` is a subtype of `Action`,  `ArrayList<Action>` is not a subtype of `ArrayList<Edge>`.

Use `ArrayList<? extends Edge>` instead.

You could take a look at [this tutorial's 4. Wildcard section](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf), although I'd suggest to just read through it, because it is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `ArrayList<E>` is not **[covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)** on the type `E`. That is, you cannot substitute an instance of `ArrayList<Derived>` for `ArrayList<Base>` just because `Derived` inherits from `Base`.

Consider this case: `String` inherits from `Object`; **however**, if this meant you could use an `ArrayList<String>` as an `ArrayList<Object>` then the following code would be possible:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(new Integer(5)); // Integer inherits from Object
```

The above can't work, because you can't add an `Integer` to an `ArrayList<String>`. If you could, then this could happen:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = (ArrayList<String>)list;
String string = stringList.get(0); // Not a string!
```

As [Ziyao has indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098402/implementations-and-collections/7098461#7098461), the correct way to implement this is to use the `? extends Edge` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

A banana **is a** fruit. A list of bananas **is not a** list of fruit.

Oherwise someone could construct a list of bananas, pass you a reference to a list of fruit, and you'd (correctly) insert an apple in it. The owner of the list of the bananas would be rightfully surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Because the *generic type must always be the same*, not something that extends from it you can rewrite like this for it to work:

```
public ArrayList<? extends Edge> getEdges() {

return A;

//A is an Arraylist of type 'Action'. Action implements Edge.

}
```