# Why can't I set HashMap<CharSequence,CharSequence> to HashMap<String,String>

Tags: java, generics

Although String implements CharSequence, Java does not allow this. What is the reason for this design decision?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098402/implementations-and-collections/7098461#7098461

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any simple way to explain why I cannot do List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Dog>()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346763/any-simple-way-to-explain-why-i-cannot-do-listanimal-animals-new-arraylistdo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The decision to disallow that was made because it's not type-safe:

```
public class MyEvilCharSequence implements CharSequence
{
    // Code here
}

HashMap<CharSequence, CharSequence> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(new MyEvilCharSequence(), new MyEvilCharSequence());
```

And now I've tried to put a `MyEvilCharSequence` into a `String` map. Big problem, since `MyEvilCharSequence` is most definitely *not* a `String`.

However, if you say:

```
HashMap<? extends CharSequence, ? extends CharSequence> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Then that works, because the compiler will prevent you from adding non-`null` items to the map. This line will produce a compile-time error:

```
// Won't compile with the "? extends" map.
map.put(new MyEvilCharSequence(), new MyEvilCharSequence());
```

[See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) for more details on generic wildcards.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `HashMap<? extends CharSequence, ? extends CharSequence>`