# Polymorphism With Data Structures

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementations and Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098402/implementations-and-collections)

My super class is Exam. One of my sub classes is Analytical.

This is a valid within my ide

```
Exam object = new Analytical();
```

However this is not.

```
ArrayList<Exam> object = new ArrayList<Analytical>();
```

The error is from new to the end of the statement and it says "Change type of object to ArrayList. So my question is how can I properly utilize polymorphis with this data structure. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098402/implementations-and-collections/

Comment: [Also worth looking at](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604477/use-of-in-collection-generics/12605337#12605337)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have different parameterized types on two sides of generic type declaration..

So, you must use the same type on both side..

It should be: -

```
ArrayList<? extends Exam> object = new ArrayList<Analytical>();
```

or

```
ArrayList<Exam> object = new ArrayList<Exam>();
```

or

```
ArrayList<? extends Exam> object = new ArrayList<Exam>();
```

Polymorphism, does not apply on the parameterized type..

Comment: Option 1 is still giving me an error from new to the end of the statement.

Comment: Howcum?? Exam is your base class right?? And Analytical your subclass?? Then it should compile..  What have you written, can you post it here?

Comment: nevermind i'm good. thank you

Comment: yep. thank you. learned something new today!

Comment: @gmustudent.. Then its good.. And you're welcome..  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to something like:

```
ArrayList<? extends Exam> object = new ArrayList<Exam>();
```

[Inheritance in generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) is little different from our regular understanding.

Comment: Or `ArrayList<? extends Exam> object = new ArrayList<Analytical>();`

Comment: Question. How will java know that I want the object type to be the Analytical subclass and not the MultipleChoice subclass for example. In other words, how can I specify the object type I desire.

Comment: If you want to keep only Analytical, not another type, then ArrayList<Analytical> object = new ArrayList<Analytical>();

Answer (score 0):

`Collections` are **checked** only during `Compilation` time not during the `Runtime`, so this measure has been taken, so that **by mistake a wrong type doesn't get into the collection**...

`ArrayList<? extends Exam> object = new ArrayList<Analytical>();`

or

`ArrayList<? extends Exam> object = new ArrayList<Exam>();`